# chrome strikes again, not loading background-image

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image

Okay, this is really annoying.

Why this simple code does not work in chrome?
http://jsfiddle.net/5d105ebx/

```
#poster {
  width: 758px;
  height: 140px;
background-image:url("http://test.fastsubtitles.ro/posters/banners/36.jpg");
}
```

It works in IE. I do not understand.

LE: ADblock was the problem. Folder where my images are is named banners so i guess that's the reason.

Comment: It works for me on Chrome v37 just fine...

Comment: I cleared the cache twice, and all i get is... http://g.iceimg.com/EQVqL8xi/untitled.png

Comment: "But it works in IE"...said no one ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear cache and reload.

If you have Chrome dev tools open, long press on the reload button for quick access to hard reload with cache clearing.

Comment: Did that, still no image. I don't get it.

Comment: God, i can't believe this... i disabled google docs extension and now it works...unbelievable.

Answer (score 1):

First Try Hard Reload, ( Ctrl+Shift+R )

Or Use just Like this.

```
background:url("http://test.fastsubtitles.ro/posters/banners/36.jpg");
```